# xsd-based code generator to build xml?

Tags: c++, xml, xsd

I have a schema (xsd), and I want to create xml files that conform to it.

I've found code generators that generate classes which can be loaded from an xml file (CodeSynthesis).  But I'm looking to go the other direction.

I want to generate code that will let me build an object which can easily be written out as an xml file.  In C++.  I might be able to use Java for this, but C++ would be preferable.  I'm on solaris, so a VisualStudio plugin won't help me (such as xsd2code).

Is there a code generator that lets me do this?

Comment: CodeSynthesis generates code that can generate xml output.  
What is it that you can't do with it?

Comment: You are correct stefaanv.  I was misinformed about CodeSynthesis.  After working with it for a while now, it almost does what I want.  The problem now is that it doesn't use virtual methods, so derived types don't quite work right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To close this out:  I did wind up using CodeSynthesis.  It worked very well, as long as I used a single xsd as its source.  Since I actually had two xsds (one imported the other), I had to manually merge them (they did some weird inheritance that needed manual massaging).

But yes, Code Synthesis was the way to go.

Comment: Can you provide some sample code for this?  I'm also looking to use Code Synthesis to create xml based on a schema, but I'm having a tough time finding examples to work from...

Comment: @tpm1510, I'd like to help you out, but I have a new job now, so I can't access the code I used.  IIRC, I followed the examples pretty closely.  The most difficult part was tweaking the xsd (which did some weird things that might actually be non-standard).

Comment: I have successfully generated XML with CodeSynthesis XSD when there was one XSD that imported other XSD files. /usr/bin/xsdcxx (the Ubuntu name of the command) needs to be run once for each XSD file.

Comment: Yes, when I used this, CodeSynthesis could properly handle an XSD import statement.  However, in my particular case, one XSD declared an element X, that inherited from the other XSD's element X, but kept the same name for the derived element.  I'm not convinced that's valid XSD syntax, but it's what I was stuck with.  The code generated by CodeSynthesis then failed to compile, because of a name collision -- `class X : public X` is not valid C++.  I could be remembering some details incorrectly though; this was years ago at a previous job.